# Rendering large data tables efficiently with Aurelia

Tags: javascript, performance, aurelia

I'm struggling with performance when rendering large data tables using Aurelia.

Even in case of moderate size tables (20x20) I'm not getting below 200ms for Chrome, MS Edge takes ~800ms and IE11 takes ~2s. The 200ms are an issue as well, if you want to add (virtual) scrolling. Processing time increases with the number of bindings per table cell. I have put together an ([example](http://plnkr.co/edit/s7k55W?p=info)) that binds 'css', 'class', and of course the cell content.

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr repeat.for="row of rows">
      <td repeat.for="column of columns" css.bind="getCellStyle(column, $parent.$first)" class.bind="getCellClasses(column, row)">
        <template replaceable part="cell-template">
          <span>${getCellText(column, row)}</span>
        </template>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas how I could improve the performance?

Based on initial proposals I tried to avoid the nested repeats but this is not possible in my case since both, columns and rows, are dynamic.

Comment: [ui-virtualization](http://aurelia.io/ui-virtualization)?

Comment: The question was about optimization for rendering visible table cells. Aurelia ui-virtualization helps, if there are many invisible rows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great question, this is something we've been heavily focused on recently.

First, avoid nesting repeats when there's a ton of data involved. We're working on a performance improvement for this scenario that will improve perf dramatically for this scenario by unrolling the templates but it's not ready for release yet.

Second, use one-time bindings wherever possible.  This will eliminate any property observation and array mutation observation overhead.

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr repeat.for="row of rows & oneTime">
      <td repeat.for="column of columns & oneTime" css.one-time="getCellStyle(column, $parent.$first)" class.one-time="getCellClasses(column, row)">
        <span>${getCellText(column, row) & oneTime}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## 12/13/2015 EDIT

The upcoming release has two changes that will cut the render time of large grids in half or even less. One of the changes improves the efficiency of one-way bindings (by far the most commonly used binding mode) and the other defers some binding work until after the initial rendering is done. This will make using `oneTime` and `oneWay` just as fast in terms of initial render. More info on these improvements here:  http://blog.durandal.io/2015/12/04/aurelia-repaint-performance-rules/

Demo here: http://jdanyow.github.io/aurelia-dbmonster/

Comment: Thanks, lloking forward to the change. However, using oneTime, the table will no longer redraw when the data set (columns) changes. How do I trigger a redraw of the view? Just read about the "signal" binding behavior in your great blog: http://www.danyow.net/aurelia-binding-behaviors/ which might help here, but signal seems not to benefit from the performance fix mentioned above.

Comment: whoa, where is that "& oneTime" documented in the repeat expression?  Pretty nifty.

Answer (score -2):

Just combine your arrays into one as mentioned.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10428922)

Comment: @MikeB Im pretty sure it directly answers his question. it literally tells him exactly what to do.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but I feel the provided Answer falls short of the guidelines mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @MikeB:  This is still an answer.  It may be *incorrect* in your eyes, but it's an answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Makoto good point, will keep this in mind for future reference.